# what is difference between common jsx and react jsx?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What is the difference between `common jsx` and `react jsx`? Is there something been added by `react` to `common jsx` syntax?

Comment: As far as I know JSX is a Facebook specification so I am a bit confused on what you mean with _common_ JSX. Do you have any link referring to the latter?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: Please note that supporting JSX syntax is not the same as supporting React. React applies specific semantics to JSX syntax that ESLint doesn’t recognize. --from the page